# Automatic menu alignment in Metropolis

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis, menu

I have a beamer code (see below) that generates some dummy slides using Metropolis theme. This specific part of the code

```
%****************************************
%****************************************
%****************************************
% PROBLEM HERE
%****************************************
%****************************************
%****************************************
\newcommand{\MenuSpacing}{50em}
\newcommand{\HorizontalPositionOfPageNumber}{11.5pt}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  % \definecolor{boxcol}{gray}{0.13}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4ex,dp=2.25ex]{palette}%
      \hspace*{\MenuSpacing}
      \MenuTextSize{\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll \hskip0pt}}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
%****************************************
%****************************************
%****************************************
```

takes care of inserting a menu on the top right of each slide. The alignment of the menu with the page number is done manually, by means of the command \MenuSpacing. When a new section is added or an old section is removed, the alignment must be reestablished by means of several recompilations and adjustments, which is quite tedious. So, I am searching for a way to make this alignment automatic. Would you have any idea about how to achieve that?

```
%!TEX program = xelatex 
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,compress,aspectratio=169]{beamer} % Aspect ratio=16:9
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{ifthen}
%****************************************
%****************************************
%****************************************
% DONE
%****************************************
%****************************************
%****************************************
%*< My Colors >
\definecolor{mywhite}   {RGB}{245, 245, 247}
\definecolor{myblue}    {RGB}{ 73, 135, 156}
\definecolor{myred}     {RGB}{255, 73,   93}

%****************************************
%****************************************
%****************************************
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\srcsizetwo}{\@setfontsize{\srcsize}{2pt}{2pt}}
\newcommand{\srcsizethree}{\@setfontsize{\srcsize}{3pt}{3pt}}
\newcommand{\srcsizefour}{\@setfontsize{\srcsize}{4pt}{4pt}}
\newcommand{\srcsizefive}{\@setfontsize{\srcsize}{5pt}{5pt}}
\newcommand{\srcsizesix}{\@setfontsize{\srcsize}{6pt}{6pt}}
\newcommand{\srcsizeseven}{\@setfontsize{\srcsize}{7pt}{7pt}}
\newcommand{\srcsizeeight}{\@setfontsize{\srcsize}{8pt}{8pt}}
\newcommand{\srcsizenine}{\@setfontsize{\srcsize}{9pt}{9pt}}
\newcommand{\srcsizeten}{\@setfontsize{\srcsize}{10pt}{10pt}}
\newcommand{\srcsizeeleven}{\@setfontsize{\srcsize}{11pt}{11pt}}
\newcommand{\srcsizetwelve}{\@setfontsize{\srcsize}{12pt}{12pt}}
%****************************************
%****************************************
%****************************************
\newcommand{\crlf}{\textbackslash}
\newcommand{\MenuTextSize}{\srcsizefour}
\newcommand{\mytitlesize}{\srcsizeeleven}
\newcommand{\mytextsize}{\srcsizeeight}
\newcommand{\mytextsizesmall}{\srcsizeeight}
\newcommand{\mytextsizesmaller}{\srcsizeseven}
\newcommand{\mytextsizeevensmaller}{\srcsizesix}

%****************************************
%****************************************
%****************************************
%*< Slide Style >
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} 
\let\olditem\item 
\renewcommand\item{\olditem\justifying}
\renewcommand{\indent}{\hspace*{1em}}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\mytextsize}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\mytextsize}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

%****************************************
%****************************************
%****************************************
%*< Slide Style >
%Loading Metropolis...
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setsansfont[BoldItalicFont={* Demi Bold Italic}, 
             ItalicFont={* Demi Bold},
             BoldFont={* Demi Bold},
             % UprightFont={* Regular}]{Fira}
             UprightFont={* Regular}]{Avenir Next}

% \setsansfont[BoldFont={Fira Sans}]{Fira Sans Light}
% \setmonofont{Fira Mono}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{Fira Sans}

\newcommand{\mycolortheme}{myblue}
\newcommand{\mycolorbackground}{mywhite}
\newcommand{\colorforegroundoftheprogressbar}{myblue}
\newcommand{\colorbackgroundoftheprogressbar}{gray}


\metroset{progressbar=foot,numbering=none, titleformat frame=regular}
% \setbeamercolor{progress bar}{fg=airforceblue, bg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{progress bar}{fg=\colorforegroundoftheprogressbar, bg=\colorbackgroundoftheprogressbar}
\setbeamercolor{palette}{bg=Black!90}
\setbeamercolor{palettew}{bg=White}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=Black!97}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty


% \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second][\nonumber]
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\mytitlesize,series=\bfseries\scshape}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=Black,bg=white}
% \setbeamerfont{normal text}{size=\mytextsizesmall}

\setbeamerfont{caption}{series=\normalfont,size=\mytextsizesmaller} 



%****************************************
%****************************************
%****************************************
% PROBLEM HERE
%****************************************
%****************************************
%****************************************
\newcommand{\MenuSpacing}{50em}
\newcommand{\HorizontalPositionOfPageNumber}{11.5pt}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  % \definecolor{boxcol}{gray}{0.13}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4ex,dp=2.25ex]{palette}%
      \hspace*{\MenuSpacing}
      \MenuTextSize{\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll \hskip0pt}}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
%****************************************
%****************************************
%****************************************



\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head}%
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head}%
  \hfill
  \srcsizefour{\color{black!30}\insertframenumber~|~\inserttotalframenumber}
  \hspace{\HorizontalPositionOfPageNumber}
  \vspace{8pt}
}


\date{}

\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} 


%****************************************
%****************************************
%****************************************
% Loading chapters 
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \AtBeginSection{}
  \section{~~Section 1}
  \begin{frame}[t,fragile,allowframebreaks]\frametitle{}
  \mytextsize
    \justifying Dummy text\ldots
  \end{frame}

  \section{~~Section 2}
  \begin{frame}[t,fragile,allowframebreaks]\frametitle{}
  \mytextsize
    \justifying Dummy text\ldots
  \end{frame}
  \section{~~Section 3}
  \begin{frame}[t,fragile,allowframebreaks]\frametitle{}
  \mytextsize
    \justifying Dummy text\ldots
  \end{frame}  
  \section{~~Section 4}
  \begin{frame}[t,fragile,allowframebreaks]\frametitle{}
  \mytextsize
    \justifying Dummy text\ldots
  \end{frame}  
  \section{~~Section 5}
  \begin{frame}[t,fragile,allowframebreaks]\frametitle{}
  \mytextsize
    \justifying Dummy text\ldots
  \end{frame}  
  \section{~~Section 6}
  \begin{frame}[t,fragile,allowframebreaks]\frametitle{}
  \mytextsize
    \justifying Dummy text\ldots
  \end{frame}   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding `\hskip0pt plus1filll \hskip0pt` on the right hand side of your navigation bar, this makes it left aligned. Instead of making your navigation bar left aligned and then manually add space in front of it, make it right aligned:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer} 

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\srcsizefour}{\@setfontsize{\srcsize}{4pt}{4pt}}
\makeatother

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\setbeamercolor{palette}{bg=Black!90}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=Black!97}
\newcommand{\HorizontalPositionOfPageNumber}{11.5pt}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4ex,dp=2.25ex]{palette}%
      \srcsizefour
      \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{\hskip0pt plus1filll \hskip0pt}{\hskip5pt}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head}%
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head}%
  \hfill
  \srcsizefour\color{black!30}\insertframenumber~|~\inserttotalframenumber
  \hspace{\HorizontalPositionOfPageNumber}
  \vspace{8pt}
}

\addtobeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{\hskip0.1cm}{}

\begin{document}
  \section{Section 1}
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{}
    Dummy text\ldots
  \end{frame}   
  \section{Section 2}
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{}
    Dummy text\ldots
  \end{frame}   
  \section{Section 3}
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{}
    Dummy text\ldots
  \end{frame}   
  \section{Section 4}
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{}
    Dummy text\ldots
  \end{frame}   
  \section{Section 5}
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{}
    Dummy text\ldots
  \end{frame}   
  \section{Section 6}
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{}
    Dummy text\ldots
  \end{frame}   
\end{document}
```

[image]